# Scrollbar track on transparent does not work

Tags: html, css

I ask why my code does not make the background color of the scrollbar track transparent.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128 , 0.5);
```

I hope you can help me somehow.

Comment: Works for me - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/VwNapLb

Comment: It is transparent. You'd can't have the text show through that area... it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I doubt making the scrollbar thumb transparent is necessary because text or elements are not really going seen behind the scrollbar thumb.

Hopefully this helps :)